# About CRS and map origin setting, What is their relation and math equation in leaflet.js via using proj4leaflet.js

Tags: leaflet, proj, proj4js, proj4leaflet

I meet a problem about CRS function and map origin setting in leaflet.
I use proj4leaflet.js as the basic CRS function, and then after setting the origin of crs and
resolution, I can get the correct maps in leaflet.js map screen, the code snippet is as following:

```
var resolutions = [
    66.1459656252646,
    26.458386250105836,
    13.229193125052918,
    6.614596562526459,
    2.6458386250105836,
    1.3229193125052918,
    0.6614596562526459,
    0.26458386250105836,
];
var origin = [-9799999, -1692600.0];
var epsg3826 = new L.Proj.CRS(
    "EPSG:3826",
    '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=121 +k=0.9999 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs',
    {
        resolutions: resolutions,
        origin: origin
    });
    
var map = L.map('mmap', {
            crs: epsg3826
        });
```

The problem comes from the more detail design for system. When I need to set a point(longitude,latitude) which format on EPSG:4326, then , after using proj4js, the result coordinate data can not directed match to the map on EPSG:3826 format. The code snippet I used  is as below:

```
var origin = [-9799999, -1692600.0];  //the CRS origin
proj4.defs('EPSG:3826', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=121 +k=0.9999 +x_0=250000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs');
proj4.defs('EPSG:3857', '+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +type=crs');
proj4.defs("EPSG:4326", "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +type=crs");
let inputCoordinates = [-52.23412404523799, 41.318099360192335];
let transformedCoordinates6 = proj4('EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3826').forward(inputCoordinates);
Transformed Coordinates6:  -316615.0671949112,15404344.837179212
```

I got a immense number of coordinate: -316615.0671949112,15404344.837179212, however it can not show the correct map position via minus the origin[-9799999, -1692600.0] directly.
I need a correct point on map in EPSG:3826 format, and then using proj4js to turn it on EPSG:4326 format, so that I could use L.marker or some other tool to draw the map in correct
location in leaflet.js map screen, like following:

```
new L.marker([-52.21990315, 41.36829856], { icon: parkIcon }).addTo(map);
```

To do that, I need a correct math equation to describe origin(from the CRS origin) and map coordinate of map points.
What I seen now is project and unproject function in leaflet.js, and how proj4leaflet.js rewrite them , as following:

```
project: function (latlng) {
        var point = this._proj.forward([latlng.lng, latlng.lat]);
        return new L.Point(point[0], point[1]);
    },

unproject: function (point, unbounded) {
        var point2 = this._proj.inverse([point.x, point.y]);
        return new L.LatLng(point2[1], point2[0], unbounded);
    },
```

but it still not enough to solve my problem.

Does any one have good idea or any material for that?

Comment: Point `[-52.23412404523799, 41.318099360192335]` is not in projected `EPSG:3857` coordinates, it's plain `EPSG:4326` (if order is `[lat, lng]`), so `proj4('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:3826').forward([-52.23412404523799, 41.318099360192335])` makes no sense.

Comment: sorry, I will re-type my post. I hope to get a math equation, which can show the relation between origin(the CRS origin) and the point in EPSG:3826 and its position after transformed via proj4js in EPSG:4326. The main reason is the origin I got is from try and error, not the correct data in map, I hope to derived a math equation to describe this situation, and then I can draw map in correct position, even the map data is from WMTS MapServer in EPSG:3826 format.

Comment: Is `[-52.23412404523799, 41.318099360192335]` in [lng, lat] or [lat, lng] coordinates? Either way it falls in the middle of the sea. Where this is supposed to be on the globe?

Comment: This value is from mouse event in leaflet.js map screen ; I got it from [e.latlng.lat,e.latlng.lng]. the map data is from wtms, not on the globe. The map is independent and a part of the globe, so its origin is very different to globe. And that's why I need a math equation to find the relation between origin and the point I hope to projection the EPSG:4326

Comment: Sorry, but it's not clear what are you trying to achieve. CRS `EPSG:3826` is for limited area of Taiwan (see https://epsg.io/3826). Coordinates `[-52.23412404523799, 41.318099360192335]` are nowhere near this area. It's not clear what your initial problem is, you are just describing how you want to solve it. Can you share URL of mentioned WMTS map server?

Comment: I can't provide that, it somehow has some privacy policy limitation. The main problem is that the origin I set is come from try and error, and after it works, the crs function proj4leaflet.js provided can make sure the https:................MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/....../{z}/{y}/{x}.png can work well.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your question you mention that you are looking for origin (top left corner) of tile matrix for WMTS layer. Please edit your question and add that info to the body of the question.

To get origin (top left corner) of tile matrix for WMTS layer you can use `GetCapabilities` request. Then in the result (XML) look up for you layer, see what `TileMatrixSet` it is using, find it's definition and there you'll find `TopLeftCorner` for each scale. If you are lucky all scales will have the same origin.

For example, if your request WMTS capabilities for https://prostor4.gov.si/ows2-gwc-pub/service/wmts service, you'll find that layer `SI.GURS.DK:DTK5_D48` uses `EPSG:3912_DTK5` matrix set, but info for this set says for example that scale `1500000.0` has origin `370210.0 235895.0`, but scale `500000.0` has origin `370210.0 200055.0`.